Google Authentication Avatar
  public function callback()
    {
        $googleUser = Socialite::driver('google')->user();
        
        $user = User::updateOrCreate(
            ['google_id' => $googleUser->id],
            [
                'name' => $googleUser->name,
                'email' => $googleUser->email,
                'password' => Str::password(12),
                'email_verified_at' => now(),
                'image' => $googleUser->getAvatar(),
            ]
        );

the line gives the full path to the Google avatar and if you open it in a browser it works
  'image' => $googleUser->getAvatar(),

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACg8ocLnBsb67U_duAICud3t95-OL5c4ujmno8osiI1KLh1lTy7p9k0=s96-c
look for yourself it's a google avatar
tell me how to display it on the front
<img
     class="rounded-full"
     width="95"
     :src="userImage"
            >

or should this be done via
GET https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me


Use the direct Google avatar URL (https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/...). It’s simpler and avoids the need for additional API requests.
